# Subscribe to GCP pub/sub with AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda

We need to consume messages from a GCP pub/sub topic using an AWS lambda. Most solutions I found are for the opposite, can someone point me to an example on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Expose your Lambda function via a [Function URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html), or via [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/). Configure a GCP pub/sub [Push subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push) for that URL.

The Lambda function would receive the message as part of the `event` object. It would need to parse out the message, handle whatever processing is required, and then return the appropriate status code to acknowledge the message.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I'll have look in time when we move to integration and come back to you if more support is needed. Thank you again